# Combo box appears to be empty when switching frames?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jcombobox

`Addstudent` Frame with 5 comboboxes have the boxes filled with different arrays.
Currently, when the frame is ran on its own, the comboboxes are fine; all the items of the array I want displayed, are displayed.

However, when I switch from the frame and comeback to it, `e.g. (via button actions) AddStudent frame-> NewFrame -> AddStudent frame`, *the comboboxes appear empty, with no arrays loaded onto them.*

**button to switch from the "NewFrame" to the "AddStudent" frame**

```
 private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        ComboboxFrame CF = new ComboboxFrame();
        CF.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);

    }
```

**The coding of "AddStudent" frame which is used to load array into the comboboxes**

```
public class AddStudent extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form AddStudent
     */
public AddStudent() 
{
    initComponents();
}

    List<String> sundayList;
    List<String> mondayList;
    List<String> tuesdayList;
    List<String> wednesdayList;
    List<String> thursdayList;

    private void loadLists() throws IOException
    {
        //Creating the array of Activities to put into the ComboBoxes
        File f = new File("Activities.dat");

        sundayList = new ArrayList<>();
        mondayList= new ArrayList<>();
        tuesdayList= new ArrayList<>();
        wednesdayList= new ArrayList<>();
        thursdayList= new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

            while(reader.ready())
            {
                String CDay = reader.readLine();                               
                String CActivityName = reader.readLine();
                String CSupervisor = reader.readLine();
                String CLocation = reader.readLine();
                String CPaid = reader.readLine();
                String nothing = reader.readLine();

                if(CDay.equals("Sunday"))
                {
                    sundayList.add(CActivityName);
                }
                else if(CDay.equals("Monday"))
                {
                    mondayList.add(CActivityName);
                }
                else if(CDay.equals("Tuesday"))
                {
                    tuesdayList.add(CActivityName);
                }
                else if(CDay.equals("Wednesday"))
                {
                    wednesdayList.add(CActivityName);
                }
                else if(CDay.equals("Thursday"))
                {
                    thursdayList.add(CActivityName);
                }                
            }
            sundayList.add("-");
            mondayList.add("-");
            tuesdayList.add("-");
            wednesdayList.add("-");
            thursdayList.add("-");
            reader.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(StartUpFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
               comboboxSunday.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(sundayList.toArray(new String[sundayList.size()])));
               comboboxMonday.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(mondayList.toArray(new String[mondayList.size()])));
               comboboxTuesday.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(tuesdayList.toArray(new String[tuesdayList.size()])));
               comboboxWednesday.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(wednesdayList.toArray(new String[wednesdayList.size()])));
               comboboxThursday.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(thursdayList.toArray(new String[thursdayList.size()])));
    }
...
...
...
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AddStudent addStudent = new AddStudent();
                    addStudent.loadLists();
                    addStudent.setVisible(true);                                   
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddStudent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sure this has already been asked today. Basically it comes down to the method loadList not been called. How is ComboFrame related to AddSgudent?

Comment: `the comboboxes appear empty, with no arrays loaded onto them. ` that not possible, issue must be in code that you not showing here, have to debug this issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer the question has been edited..ComboFrame does not exist anymore; I've mentioned in my previous comments
Also, as I've asked before, I wrote that the method loadList has been called near the end of the coding above, where the frame is created and viewed.

Comment: from your description it looks like the code doesn't show the case when it's _breaking_ so is rather .. useless ..

Comment: @kleopatra what do you mean? as in, the code doesn't explicitly show errors, so it's not fixable? D:

Comment: Would binding the method `loadLists` to the button which switches frames fix the problem, possibly..?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you're clicking the button, you're creating a new Frame.  Does the new frame share elements (like the combo boxes) with the original?  Java Swing is pretty picky on what you can re-use and what you cannot.  As a basic guideline, Models are safe to re-use, but the JComponents should live on their own (i.e. you can share Models across frames but not the JComponents themselves).